# What strain of yeast is Fermentis BE-134?

Tags: yeast

The [spec sheet](https://fermentis.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/SafAle-BE-134_Rev2.pdf) says:

> The SafAle™ BE-134 is a Saccharomyces cerevisiae var. diastaticus and is characterized by a particularly high
>   attenuation.
>   This typical yeast strain is recommended for Belgian Saison-style beers. It gives fruity aromas with a slight spicy
>   character (POF+) such as clove notes. This strain will bring highly refreshing and drinkable beers.

It seems like none of the yeast producers makes claims as to equivalence between their yeast and the alternative producer, but there are some cross reference charts that seem somewhat reliable (and a few 'substitution' charts that aren't as useful).  I was trying to find a reliable reference that contained this particular yeast, but came up empty.

With today's ability to do genome sequencing and end point polymerase chain reaction (PCR), it would seem that a definitive source would be available, and would contain the equivalency information for BE-134.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, they are selling diastaticus by itself?! Many breweries are having problems with that strain, there was even a lawsuit from Left Hand against Whitelabs because they sold yeast that also had diastaticus in it.

https://www.goodbeerhunting.com/sightlines/2017/12/11/its-fairly-widespread-yeast-contamination-in-the-wake-of-left-hands-lawsuit

Comment: Holey molardass, I didn’t know left hand had been going through such rough times. Love that brewery!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Milk the Funk Wiki](http://www.milkthefunk.com/wiki/Saccharomyces#Other_Labs), reporting on `BE-134` they once said that "This might be the same strain as WY3711", but the linkage between BE-134 and WY3711 was removed after I asked the wiki owner's about it.  Unfortunately, there was no other linkage offered.

When `BE-134` was introduced, there was speculation that since this was a "Belgian Saison" yeast, it might be the same as the `Dupont` variety.  I have not seen any indication that this is true, though.

All these yeasts have been determined to be of the *diastaticus* variety, but that is quite common among commercially sold yeasts.  For instance, that same wiki confirms that "Belgian Golden" (Duvel) yeasts, such as `WLP570` and "Belgian Saison" (Dupont) yeasts, such as `WLP565` and `WY3724`, all are of the *diastaticus* variety. The "Milk the Funk Wiki" page currently lists 14 yeast strains from White Labs, Wyeast, Lallemand, and Fermentis (those are the brands easily available to me) that are of the *diastaticus* variety.  This variety is considered a problem in commercial breweries at low cell count when unintentionally introduced.

As more information is obtained, I hope to update this answer because the information obtained so far only allows for speculation.